# Access newtype in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm using a newtype, wrapping an array of integers:

```
struct Foo([int, ..5]);
```

Since, apparently, I cannot simply do this:

```
let foo = Foo([1,2,3,4,5]);
let bar = foo[2];
```

How exacty do I access the wrapped array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are one-and-a-half (soon to be two) ways:

```
#![feature(tuple_indexing)]

struct Foo([int, ..5]);

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo([1,2,3,4,5]);
    let Foo([_, foo_1, ..]) = foo;
    let foo_3 = foo.0[3];

    println!("[_, {}, _, {}, _]", foo_1, foo_3);
}
```

Specifically, `tuple_indexing` is likely to be un-gated soon, so you won't need the `feature` attribute to use it.

Basically, `Foo` is a *tuple struct*; that is, it behaves more or less just like a tuple that happens to have a name.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the tuple indexing way is the one with `foo.0` being the `[int, ..5]`.